# How should I Handle duplicate times in time series data with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-processing

I have the following returned from an API Call as part of a larger dataset:

> {'Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 21, 18, 18, 1,
> tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Price': '0.052600'}
>
> {'Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 21, 18, 18, 1, tzinfo=tzutc()),
> 'Price': '0.052500'}

Ideally I would use the timestamp as an index on the pandas data frame however this appears to fail as there is a duplicate when converting to JSON:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']))
print(new_df.to_json(orient='index'))
```

> ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.

Any guidance on the best way to deal with this situation? Throw away one datapoint? The time does not get more fine-grain than to the second, and there is obviously a price change during that second.

Comment: Well you need to tell us how you handle multiple price events at the same time tick: keep first, last, all? keep the first price? average price? max and min price? ...? It depends on what you're ultimately doing with the data. You need to tell us more context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can change duplicates datetimes by adding `ms` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
d = [{'Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 21, 18, 18, 1), 'Price': '0.052600'},
     {'Time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 21, 18, 18, 1), 'Price': '0.052500'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
      Price                Time
0  0.052600 2017-05-21 18:18:01
1  0.052500 2017-05-21 18:18:01

print (pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('Time').cumcount(), unit='ms'))
0          00:00:00
1   00:00:00.001000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

df['Time'] = df['Time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('Time').cumcount(), unit='ms')
print (df)
      Price                    Time
0  0.052600 2017-05-21 18:18:01.000
1  0.052500 2017-05-21 18:18:01.001
```

---

```
new_df = df.set_index('Time')
print(new_df.to_json(orient='index'))
{"1495390681000":{"Price":"0.052600"},"1495390681001":{"Price":"0.052500"}}
```

Comment: Yes this works - Thanks.  The change is price is more important than the accuracy of the time down to ms.

Comment: Super. Btw, it only change to `ms` duplicates, all unique values are not changed, because add `0ms`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use .duplicated to keep first or last entry. Have a look at [pandas.DataFrame.duplicated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Comment: No, because lost price, which is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand upon the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128685/4391298): adding a loop helps for dealing with any new duplicates introduced by the first pass.

This `isnull` is important to catch any NaTs in your data. Since any timedelta + `NaT` is still `NaT`.

```py
def deduplicate_start_times(frame, col='start_time', max_iterations=10):
    """
    Fuzz duplicate start times from a frame so we can stack and unstack
    this frame.
    """

    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        dups = frame.duplicated(subset=col) & ~pandas.isnull(frame[col])

        if not dups.any():
            break

        LOGGER.debug("Removing %i duplicates", dups.sum())

        # Add several ms of time to each time
        frame[col] += pandas.to_timedelta(frame.groupby(col).cumcount(),
                                          unit='ms')

    else:
        LOGGER.error("Exceeded max iterations removing duplicates. "
                     "%i duplicates remain", dups.sum())

    return frame
```