# The most elegant way to add rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most elegant way to append row in data frame like this:

```
     a    b   time
 0  nan  nan   8
 1  nan  nan   5
 2  nan  nan   3
```

into:

```
     a    b   time
 0  nan  nan   8
 1  nan  nan   7
 2  nan  nan   6
 3  nan  nan   5
 4  nan  nan   4
 5  nan  nan   3
 6  nan  nan   2
 7  nan  nan   1
 8  nan  nan   0
```

what I've tried is to build a function `missing_times` witch returns me new data frame with missing time but than I have with problem compressing both databases together. What is the most effective way to do this kind of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor with [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.arange(df['time'].max() + 1)[::-1]})
       .reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
    a   b  time
0 NaN NaN     8
1 NaN NaN     7
2 NaN NaN     6
3 NaN NaN     5
4 NaN NaN     4
5 NaN NaN     3
6 NaN NaN     2
7 NaN NaN     1
8 NaN NaN     0
```

If values in original df use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print (df)
   a  b  time
0  4  5     8
1  2  8     5
2  1  2     3


df = df.set_index('time')
       .reindex(np.arange(df['time'].max() + 1)[::-1])
       .reset_index()
       .reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
     a    b  time
0  4.0  5.0     8
1  NaN  NaN     7
2  NaN  NaN     6
3  2.0  8.0     5
4  NaN  NaN     4
5  1.0  2.0     3
6  NaN  NaN     2
7  NaN  NaN     1
8  NaN  NaN     0
```

Solution with duplicates in `time` column with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print (df)
   a  b  time
0  4  5     8
1  2  3     8
2  1  2     3

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.arange(df['time'].max() + 1)[::-1]})
df = pd.merge(df,df1, how='outer').sort_values('time', ascending=False)
print (df)
     a    b  time
0  4.0  5.0     8
1  2.0  3.0     8
3  NaN  NaN     7
4  NaN  NaN     6
5  NaN  NaN     5
6  NaN  NaN     4
2  1.0  2.0     3
7  NaN  NaN     2
8  NaN  NaN     1
9  NaN  NaN     0
```

Comment: I very much like your answer! But you are building new Data Frame so if there are some values in a or b will be replace with Nan. In this case would you still use this kind of code or you would build something else?

Comment: I add my first solution if same values in original dataframe. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you, but i just figured out that i have duplicates in my data frame so reindex won't work. Do you have some more suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Is possible deduplicate data by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128685/2901002) solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach, it is 4 steps:

- Set time as index
- Use reindex to create the missing entries
- Invert the order so that max(time) is on top
- Reset the index

Code:

```
df.set_index('time')\
  .reindex(range(max(df['time']) + 1))\
  .sort_index(ascending = False)\
  .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you want to do is join the tables in such a way that no row is duplicated between the two tables, which I'll call df1 and df2, you can use:

```
df3 = pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
df3.sort_values(by='time', ascending=False)
```